# Error (in GTK?) when trying to install EclipseXul plugin

Tags: gtk, plugins, eclipse

When [installing EclipseXul plugin](http://eclipsexul.sourceforge.net/chapter-installation.html) on EclipsePHP, it says:

> Cannot complete the install because
>   one or more required items could not
>   be found.   Software currently
>   installed: Shared profile
>   1.0.0.1288098146566 (SharedProfile_epp.package.php
>   1.0.0.1288098146566)   Missing requirement: Shared profile
>   1.0.0.1288098146566 (SharedProfile_epp.package.php
>   1.0.0.1288098146566) requires 'SharedProfile_epp.package.php
>   [1.0.0.1288098145696]' but it could
>   not be found

Any idea what's wrong?

When running from the terminal, I can see a message, when I open the updates windows:

> ** (Eclipse:3364): CRITICAL **: murrine_style_draw_box: assertion
>   `height >= -1' failed

Recently I have my whole home folder deleted by a script. Maybe there's something with this.. But I just downloaded a brand new Eclipse installation and put it in my /home/eclipse/ folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading other eclipse it worked just fine.. It was something wrong with my eclipse-php